# What happened to RetryOperationsInterceptor? (spring-batch)

Tags: spring, spring-batch, aop, spring-retry

For retry functions, I want to use
`org.springframework.batch.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor`.

I can find it in spring-batch 2.1.X,
but not in spring-batch 2.2.X.

Was it deleted? Did it have a problem?

If it was deleted and there is a different approach I should use instead, what is it?

Comment: I think it has been moved to spring-retry project

Answer (score 5):

It was moved to a separate project [spring-retry](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry). It is now used by multiple projects including Spring Integration and Spring AMQP.

The current version is 1.1.2.RELEASE.